# Laravel /public/home 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, laravel

My local laravel project starts with a

/public/home 500 (Internal Server Error)

in place of load all the view. Any suggestion? 
I tried git stash to last commit, .htaccess modifications, clear view and caches but it's continues.

Comment: check permissions and file ownership with `chown` and `chmod` commands.

Comment: Did you try to `composer install`?

Comment: What about logs: php, server?

Comment: still an issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can try updating the permissions and ownership with the following commands from the projects root directory.

On Nginx / Homestead:

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

On Mac:

```
sudo chgrp -R _www storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

If all else fails:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you give your tmp folder 777 permission? Or delete

```
**storage/meta/compiled.php**
```

Or try

```
ph**p artisan optimize**
```

in your app's directory